# Vuejs components to wait for initialisation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

To give some context, I've a [vuejs](https://vuejs.org) application using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) and [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

- `app.vue` Bootstrap code
- `foo.vue` Some component that renders on route `/foo`
- `bar.vue` Some component that renders on route `/bar`

When the application starts I need to sync the state reading from device storage. Since this is an async operation it's wrapped on a `vue-action` and called on `app.vue`.

When entering the `/foo` route by the time the component is mounted the `$store` is not yet update from the device storage

**How can all components ensure the initialisation is made before they are mounted?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I do in these situations is use a `v-if` on your root `<router-view>` element to render only when the data you expect to be there has populated, e.g.

```
<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      hasLoadedData() {
        // Or whatever criteria you decide on to represent that the
        // app state has finished loading.
        return this.$store.state.something !== null;
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view v-if="hasLoadedData" />
    <p v-else>Loading...</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is very interesting, although I think I'll would have to be creative about the value to watch from state, since the values are there, but may not be updated... The application state has default values.

Comment: @a--m In cases like that I create a `loaded` variable in the store somewhere and update that when all my async stuff I need to render the app is finished.